# removeFirst node in a doubly-linked list

Tags: java

I found this code about a doubly-linked list.

```
/**
 * this method removes element from the start of the linked list
 * @return
 */
public E removeFirst() {
    if (size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node tmp = head;
    head = head.next;
    head.prev = null;
    size--;
    System.out.println("deleted: "+tmp.element);
    return tmp.element;
}
```

the above code is from here : http://java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/doubly-linked-list/

I did rewrite that code in another way like this :

```
public E removeFirst() {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Node tmp = head.next;
    Node tmpExtra = head; 
    head=tmp;
    head.prev=null;
    return tmpExtra.element
}
```

Is my code correct? Am I thinking right?
Thanks

Comment: Aren't you supposed to return the removed node?

Comment: you mean `Node tmpExtra = head; return tmpExtra.element`

Comment: Did you try it? One of the rules on Stackoverflow is “tell us what you have tried”. I’d be looking for different kinds of errors depending on whether you never ran your code or you tested it with lists of lengths 0, 1 and 2 already.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the list. As far as I can tell from the code you are linking to, its `removeLast` method will leave `head` referring to the removed element if this is the only element in the list. If this is correct, it means that your rewrite may sometimes return an element that was previously removed from the list using `removeLast`, which is not correct.

Comment: thanks .. I have a question : why the get method in a linked list costs O(n^2) in the following code : `public static <E> boolean hasTwoOccurences(List<E> list, E x) {
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
if (list.get(i).equals(x)) {
count++;
}
}
return count >= 2;
}`

Comment: Now that’s hard to read! Anyway, correct me if I’m wrong, but I think that `get()` in itself takes O(n) (if you’re using a doubly linked list) so the whole piece of code takes O(n^2).

Comment: thanks ,, you mean O(n) for the for loop and O(n) for get(i) so totally is O(n^2)?

Comment: Something like that. The loop runs n times, but I’m in doubt whether it’s correct to say O(n) for the loop when what’s inside the loop is not constant (O(1)).

Comment: Ole V.V. thank you very much God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the *correct code*.

Your code clearly **does not behave the same** with the given example. For instance, you do not throw an *Exception* in the case of an empty list and you do not decrement the size of the list.

Comment: `if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }` is same like `if (size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();`

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you in that part that they mean the same; however returning a null value and throwing an exception are pretty different things.

Comment: thanks .. is it ok if I rewrite it like this : `if (head == null) {throw new NoSuchElementExcepti‌​on(); }`